# WordPress filter before category page prints content

Tags: php, wordpress

I would like to edit/inject some HTML before it's printed on the page in WordPress, I found filters like:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'apiResultInjection' );
```

This injects my content into a post page, but sometimes I need do it in a category page, that lists posts, and I couldn't find the right filter for it.

Do you know of any filters I can use?

The page is: http://www.onlinecasinoarchives.com/lottery/powerball-lottery/

And I wanted to alter the HTML template after the author block just for this specific page, and others to come.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
add_filter( 'the_excerpt', 'apiResultInjection' );
```